# Are there any other tags that have the href attribute except <a>?

Tags: html

I hope this is a suitable question for pro webmasters. Are there any othertags that have the href attribute except `<a>`? If yes, please tell me which. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to know?

Answer (score 7):

No, the following tags have it too (HTML 5):

- area
- base
- link

Comment: +1, I missed `<base>`. Probably because I never use it.

Comment: +1 ... and you can find out just about everything you might want to know about X/HTML standards by reading the specifications at [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/)